# How to search through multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

My table called 'posts' has 3 columns, namely morning, afternoon and evening.
Now I need to do search through this three columns for data. Now both columns value and data to search for are supplied by user. SO the value could be array or single value.

Question is how to search through multiple columns?

part of the query which needed to be corrected .

```
$sql .= " AND posts.".$cols." IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')";
```

values for the above mentioned columsn are stored as a comma seperated string. That's why `IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')`

But `$cols` represent columns. I need to search through the column supplied by user which could be morning, or morning, afternoon and so fort for the data. Finding data in a column is not a problem. BUt to search through columns that's supplied by user is. Because if they give single value it has no issue but if its an array?

sample data for `$cols`

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'morning' (length=7)
  1 => string 'afternoon' (length=9)
  2 => string 'evening' (length=7)
```

sample data for $days

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If sequance `$cols` and `$days` arrays is same, then you can loop over `$cols` and add to sql query its search part for each `col` and `day`

```
// Like this
foreach($cols as $k => $col){
     $sql .= " AND posts.".$col." =  ".$days[$k]." )";
}
```

Comment: both $cols and $days carries caries different array values? Can I still use this?

Comment: no you should somehow modify your data retrieve part so at the end you will have in 2 arrays values in exact sequence by that i mean `$cols[0](morning)` value should be `$days[0](Sun)`, `$cols[1](afternoon)` values is `$days[1](Sun)`, 2 ->  2 ...